# Allow access for chrome://cache/ and chrome://view-http-cache pages from background page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing extension for google chrome and i need to have access to chrome cache. It might be possible if i have access for chrome://cache/ and chrome://view-http-cache/[url] pages from extension but i can`t found way how to do this.

Is possible to do this in chrome extension context?

Comment: There's a flag in chrome://flags to enable this, though it's strongly discouraged.

Comment: However when i enabled this flag i can't do actions like executing scripts from background or send messages.

Comment: Solved this problem by add "chrome://*/*" in manifest -> permissions